Investing an inheritance and paying capital gains tax to fund ISAs
I have an inheritance coming shortly of about £300,000 in cash. I anticipate using an online platform to invest it in, say, a global index ETF. However, it would seem sensible to also fund a stocks & shares ISA each year by selling shares and reinvesting in the ISA - possibly using a 'Bed and ISA' arrangement - progressively moving shares from the dealing account into ISA protection. Obviously, initially I can put the full allowable amount (£20,000) into an ISA account and the rest into a dealing account. After the first year (or so), I will then be able to raise enough cash by selling shares up to the CGT allowance (gain <= £3000) to fully fund an ISA. So far, so good.
However, as time goes on (assuming good growth of the EFT), there will soon come a point where selling shares without exceeding the capital gains tax-free allowance will not fully fund the ISA. The question is: if I wish to maximise the total usable value (ie, remaining dealing account after any tax + ISA) at some point in the future, is it better 1) to limit myself to only realising shares within the CGT allowance and pay no tax at the time (but transfer rapidly dwindling numbers of shares into ISA protection each year), or 2) to realise enough cash to fully fund the ISA each year and pay the capital gains tax each time?
There are lots of online recommendations to fully utilise the CGT allowance each year and transfer the proceeds to an ISA (which is obviously beneficial), but I have found nothing regarding the benefit (or not) of paying CGT each year in order to maximise ISA contributions.
I have done some simplistic calculations myself and it seems that, somewhat counter-intuitively, it is actually worthwhile to pay the CGT (losing some shares in the process) in order to maximise the ISA transfer values - assuming that, at some point in the future, the aim is to cash in (and use) the total investment (when any shares still remaining in the dealing account will then be subject CGT whereas the ISA shares won't). Could it be that, in this case, paying tax early on is better than paying tax later? I give my working below - I would be very grateful for other opinions on the validity of this, and the problem in general. I'm worried that this seems too good to be true...

Scenario:
Compare selling an extra number of shares (ie, above the CGT-free allowance, but still within the ISA total contribution limit), paying CGT from the proceeds, and then reinvesting the residue in an ISA - with - leaving the same number of shares unsold, outside the ISA, and then paying CGT when they are eventually sold.
Assumptions:
the ISA selling and rebuying prices are the same;
dealing charges are negligible;
the CGT rate remains the same over the period up to final disposal;
the whole of the (to ISA) sale of the extra shares will be subject to CGT since the annual allowance has already been used;
the whole of the final (non-ISA) sale of the extra shares will also be subject to CGT since that year's allowance will have been used on the sale of the remaining bulk of the inheritance;
the tax is assumed to be paid out of the proceeds of any sale;
the same growth factor will apply whether within an ISA or not.
The formulae apply to an arbitrary single year's transaction, but can be repeated every year.
The formulae assume that appropriate tax will be paid. If the input values are outside the assumed conditions, the notional tax may become negative: obviously zero tax would be payable under these circumstances and the formulae would lead to an incorrect result.

X = current value of the 'extra portion' of the inheritance under consideration
C = original cost of the extra portion
G = growth factor after an arbitrary time before selling everything
t = CG tax rate
K = cash realised on future sale (after tax) of the extra portion if kept intact
I = cash realised on selling the (taxed) extra portion if sheltered in an ISA
nett proceeds = sale value - taxable gain . tax rate
taxable gain = sale value - original cost (no allowance)
growth factor = the fractional change in value over a given arbitrary period until final disposal, eg, (1 + growth rate)^years for a constant rate; G>1 represents positive growth, G<1 represents a loss in value

Keep the investment extra portion intact outside the ISA; it grows for a further period, and is then taxed according to its initial cost when sold:
K  =  X.G  -  [X.G - C].t  =  X.G.(1-t)  +  C.t
Transfer the investment extra portion to an ISA; it is taxed according to its original cost, and the residual then grows for a further period, but is not subject to tax when sold:
I  =  ( X - [X - C].t ).G  =  X.G.(1-t)  +  C.t.G

Difference I - K = C.t.(G - 1) which is always positive if G>1

Note that the difference does not depend directly on the sizes of the CGT or ISA allowances (though the size of X, and hence C, will).
Edit: @Henry has commented that any dividends accrued by the investment (portion) will be subject to tax if not within an ISA wrapper. Dividends, and any consequent taxation, will depend heavily (and rather unquantifiably) on the nature of the investment and the personal circumstances of the investor. Moreover, dividends may occur on several discrete occasions after the comparison starts but before the point in the future when the whole investment is sold. The ethos of this comparison is that taxation is paid, as it occurs, out of the proceeds of investment sales, so it is reasonable to assume that dividends will be reinvested (which may happen automatically with an accumulation investment). Nevertheless, the positive effects of any dividend(s) will apply equally to both investment portions being considered (in the form of additional units, albeit not at the original cost), but dividend taxation will only apply to the portion kept outside the ISA wrapper and will always reduce its final nett value since a number of units will have been sold to pay it. Hence, the occurrence of taxable dividends will only increase the relative advantage of payment of CGT to maximise ISA contributions in this comparison.
Therefore it is better to transfer the maximum possible to an ISA and pay CG tax at the time (even if the CGT-free allowance has already been used up) than to retain excess outside an ISA and pay tax in the future when it is sold. It is always good to move at least the tax-free allowance to an ISA. An additional bonus is that maximum ISA transfer each year accomplishes total transfer of shares to ISA protection in a dramatically shorter time than if only the CGT allowance route is taken.

Your question seems to boil down to "Is it better to do X or Y" and you've looked online and found all the recommendations say to do X, and you've done your own calculation and it shows X is better... so what is the sticking point?

You might also consider putting some of the money into a personal pension (various limits to be aware of).

@Vicky my calculations show that Y is better. The sticking points: are my calculations actually wrong? and, if not, why does this option not seem to be talked about?

@TripeHound thank you for the reminder about pensions and their limitations - it's not an option for me - but I'm primarily interested in the general notion of paying CGT to put more money into ISAs

I do not see income tax on dividends in your calculations.   Even with an accumulation ETF, this would be due each year on anything held outside an ISA (or pension fund).

@Henry If dividends are simply reflected in the share price of a fund, the equations remain the same. If the dividends are paid out, those applicable to the comparative portion outside the ISA will be taxed (as you note), reducing its nett value and making the case even stronger for paying the CGT early in order to move the maximum amount of the inheritance into ISA protection quickly. But that is assuming that the equations (and deductions from them) are correct - I am still hoping that someone will actually check the underlying equations and confirm their correctness (or otherwise)!

I’m not sure why you say it’s counter-intuitive that you should be getting as much money as you can out of the scope of taxation, even if it means paying some tax now rather than later. If you make a capital gain then you have incurred a tax liability, and it makes no difference to your overall position if you pay the tax now or defer it, only to your cashflow. The exception to this is if you lose your CGT allowance for some years by not using it, but your plan will help with this by crystallising taxable gains every year. To my intuition, your plan is obviously the best course of action.

It's only counter-intuitive because I have not found any prior discussion of voluntarily exceeding the CGT allowance to maximise funding of an ISA. There may be an elementary error in my calculations, which would explain why the topic is not discussed; but if they are correct, why is it never mentioned? - I would have thought it would be of interest to many investors. It's not just a question of deferring a tax payment for cash flow reasons - it actually makes a modest profit. I would love someone to confirm that the calculations are correct - or point out the error.
